Potremmo avere le etichette in italiano? / Could we have tags in Italian?
Sui siti Stack Exchange di francese, spagnolo e portoghese, o anche russo, la maggior parte delle etichette (se non sono tutte) sono nelle rispettive lingue. Ma qui abbiamo tutte le etichette in inglese, questo crea confusione quando qualcuno vuole trovare un'etichetta adeguata. Non abbiamo neanche i sinonimi in italiano.
Quando cercavo l'etichetta di "congiuntivo" per questa domanda, non riuscivo a trovarla. Ci sono voluti due minuti prima di trovare "subjunctive-mood".
Vorrei che avessimo le etichette in italiano. Potremmo?
(P.S. Non so parlare italiano perfettamente. Correggereste gli errori se ce ne sono?)

On the Stack Exchange sites for French, Spanish and Portuguese, or even Russian, most (if not all) tags are in the respective languages. But here all the tags are in English, this creates confusion when someone wants to find a suitable tag. We don't even have the synonyms in Italian. 
When I was looking for the "congiuntivo" tag for this question, I couldn't find it. It took me two minutes before finding "subjunctive-mood".
I'd like we had all the tags in Italian. Could we?

I corrected the mistakes, as requested, and added an English translation because it is site policy that the meta discussions are held in English (mainly for the convenience of SE employees and users that are not comfortable discussing in Italian). Feel free to correct the translation if I misinterpreted what you meant.

Regarding your question, I think it is good to keep the tags in English (again, for convenience of users with a not too high level of Italian and also because SE's offical language is English), but it would make a lot of sense to create tag synonyms in Italian

I agree with @DenisNardin. As you can see we have already (at present very few) tag synonyms in Italian. I would like to encourage users of this site to create more of them.

@DenisNardin: I think it would be also a good idea to translate the question title into English, maybe maintaining both versions as in this question.

I think it is good to keep the tags in English (again, for convenience of users with a not too high level of Italian and also because SE's offical language is English), but it would make a lot of sense to create tag synonyms in Italian.
I will try to set apart some time next week to create those synonyms, but since we're talking about a fair number of tags all users with enough reputation to contribute should feel free to do so.

As pointed out, French, Spanish and Portuguese have all their tags in their respective languages, while Russian has a mix of English and their own language of tags. I can confirm that for the three Romance language sites, they have English synonyms for all the tags, so having the "main entry" in Italian shouldn't be a problem.

@iBug I am not comfortable making too many changes at once. If we create the Italian -> English synonyms it's relatively easy to swap them later if we so choose. But let's see what the rest of the community says.
